# Regarding: Apple M1 Ultra with 20-core CPU

Tags: mac, cpu

If I run `top` or `htop` on it-- what would I see?

40 CPUs or 20?

It's a legitimate question: I don't expect to be "voted down" for it.....

Comment: Sometimes people downvote for no obvious reason, sometimes because they think the question lacks details or research.

Comment: Having said that: top doesn't show number of CPUs AFAIK, htop on a plain M1 shows eight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The M1 CPU doesn't do Hyperthreading, like Intel CPUs, so 20 cores is 20 cores.

`top` doesn't give me a CPU count on my M1 Pro MBP.

`htop` is not included with MacOS.